# How to capture schema of a JSON file using Talend

Tags: talend

I'm trying to capture the schema of a JSON file that I am generating from a SQL database using Talend. I need to store this schema in a separate file. Does anyone know of a way to capture this?

Answer (score 1):

With the metadata section in repository, you can create a JSON File Schema. Here you can import a json file example , it will then generate a schema that you could reuse in the output of your job, in a twritejsonfields component for example.